# grep for duration=N while N is longer than X, the position of this sentence changes between lines

Tags: bash, grep

I have a very long file with a format of `column_name=column_val, column_name2=column_val2` and so on.

the columns are not in the right order, lets say for example i have this file:

```
bar=x moshe=foo test=x duration=5
moshe=foo2 test=y duration=0 bar=y
duration=3 moshe=foo3 bar=z test=x
```

i want to return lines only where duration is greater then 2

as far as I know `awk` is not optional since i can't tell where the columns are location in each line.

on IRC in `#bash` channel someone recommended using gawk's match(). there too i was having problem seeing how to resolve this while each line the duration is elsewhere.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `there too i was having problem seeing how to resolve this while each line the duration is elsewhere.` What problem? Match it, extract the digit after `=`, compare.

Comment: Your statement: `far as I know awk is not optional...` indeed seems to support such conclusion. `awk` is a whole language capable of anything.

Comment: @KamilCuk - you helped me understand how much i don't know awk :) i'll go read the tutorial. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the data with regex and compare.

```
awk '0+gensub(".*duration=([0-9]*).*", "\\1", "1") > 2'
```

@edit as above, the `0+` is needed to convert string to integer.

Comment: [Here's a good awk introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duration=` as field separator:

```sh
# showing field content in numeric context
$ awk -F'duration=' '{print +$2}' ip.txt
5
0
3

# use required numeric comparison to get desired output
$ awk -F'duration=' '+$2 > 2' ip.txt
bar=x moshe=foo test=x duration=5
duration=3 moshe=foo3 bar=z test=x
```

- See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html for conversion details
- Unary `+` works on `GNU awk`, not sure about other versions. `0+$2` should work everywhere to force numeric context.

**Note** that if you have multiple `duration=` in a line, only the first one will be tested.

Comment: @anubhava that didn't work when I tested with `duration=03`

Comment: You are right. I had tested with `05` and for some reason that worked

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `grep`:

```
grep -E 'duration=([3-9] |[0-9]{2,})' "file"
```

Comment: the duration is dynamic, it's not always two. but if i won't find a proper solution to work with this is a nice way to go. thanks

Comment: @ufk `it's not always two`? What did mean by that? `[3-9] ` finds 3-9 and space, `[0-9]{2,}` finds at least 2 digits. Of course it won't work if you have durations that begins with zeros e.g. 02,003,00100, etc.

Comment: i mean if the number is great then 59, or greater than 105343, for each one i will need to build a different numbers matching for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
     awk '/duration/ {
         for (counter=1; counter <= NF; counter++) {
             if ($counter ~ /^duration*/) {
                 value=substr($counter, index($counter,"=")+1);
                 if (value > 2) {
                     print $0;
                 }
             }
         }
     }' <inputfile>
```